# Which features in my neural net don't matter?

Tags: neural-networks, feature-engineering

Apologies if this question has been answered elsewhere. I don't know what to even search for.

I have a small dataset which meant many of my features are hand-engineered. I have added a lot of features and now want a way to see which features can be discarded.

I don't have the processing power to iterate over every combination of features to see their impact. Is there another way?

Comment: Try Logistic Regression with L1 norm. It can serve as a baseline if you will decide to go with Neural Network anyways. If you pick the regularization parameter correctly (e.g. cross-validation; you must do it anyways for a small dataset), the model will automatically prune away the non-important features. The trained model can be (almost) interpretable in many cases.